# Smallest element in each row of matrix C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, min, function-definition

This code can only return one smallest element in a matrix, but how if I want to return smallest element in each row? I need to use recursive function in C++. Thanks for your help

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int smallest(int** arr, int rows, int columns, int column_index = 0)
{
    if (rows <= 0 || column_index >= columns)
        return INT_MAX;


    if (rows == 1)
        return min(*(*arr + column_index),       
            smallest(arr, 1, columns - 1,
                column_index + 1)); 


    return min(smallest(arr, 1, columns), 
        smallest(arr + 1, rows - 1, columns));
}
int main()
{
    int row, col, index=0;
    cin >> row;
    cin >> col;
    int** arr;
    arr = new int* [row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
         arr[i] = new int[col];
         for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
             cin >> arr[i][j];
           }
        }
    cout<<smallest(arr, row, col, index);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this much code will be sufficient if you use standard algorithm - [std::min_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int r, c;
    std::cin >> r >> c;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat(r, std::vector<int>(c));
    for (auto &&row : mat)
        for (auto &&ele : row)
            std::cin >> ele;
    for (auto &&row : mat)
        std::cout << *std::min_element(row.begin(), row.end()) << std::endl;
}
```

---

If you want to do it your way (old school style, using recursion) then do something like this. You just need to fix the index of row while calling `smallest`. Below is some self-explanatory code :

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

// here row_index represents the index of row and col represents the number of
// elements in that row which are not yet traversed (counted from beginning)
int smallest(int **arr, int row_index, int col) {

    // only first element is not traversed
    if (col == 1)
        return arr[row_index][0];

    // return minimum of last element and value returned by recursive call for
    // first col - 1 elements
    return std::min(arr[row_index][col - 1], smallest(arr, row_index, col - 1));
}

int main() {
    int row, col;
    std::cin >> row;
    std::cin >> col;
    int **arr = new int *[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[col];
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            std::cin >> arr[i][j];
    }

    // call the function for each row
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        std::cout << "Smallest element in row " << i + 1 << " : "
                  << smallest(arr, i, col) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a recursive function that finds the smallest element in a one-dimensional array that will be called for each "row" of an array of arrays or of a two-dimensional array.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

const int * smallest( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    return n < 2 ? a  
                 : std::min( a, smallest( a + 1, n - 1 ), 
                             []( const int *p1, const int *p2 )
                             {
                                return not ( *p2 < *p1 );
                             } );
}

int main() 
{
    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );
    size_t rows, cols;
    
    std::cin >> rows >> cols;
    
    int **a = new int *[rows];
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        a[i] = new int[cols];
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = std::rand() % ( rows + cols );
        }
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << a[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << *smallest( a[i], cols ) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        delete [] a[i];
    }
    
    delete [] a;
}
```

If to enter the numbers of rows and columns equal to 10 then the program output might look like

```
 1 16  7  6  2  7  1 14  3  8 
 0 14  9  0  6 18 18  7  7 19 
12 17  9 12 14 10  7  9 15  3 
14  8 19 13 14  1 12 15  7 15 
16  7  1 17 19  8 15 18  7 15 
 9 19 12 10  3 18  0 10  7  8 
 6 13 16 17  7  3 19 19 18  6 
 7 14  6  8  3 17  8 19  7 16 
 6 16  7 10 19 11  1 19 13  8 
19 19 14  8 17  1 11  8 12  1 

 1  0  3  1  1  0  3  3  1  1
```

Pay attention to that the function should return a pointer to a smallest element because in general the function can be called with the second argument equal to 0. In this case returning any integer value does not make a sense because it can coincide with an actual value.

Comment: or return `std::optional<int>`